# I can't access the fields on a struct array

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, data-structures, struct

I'm learning how to program and I reached a roadblock on something I've been making. Once I to the function I print the value of the disp field but it says "0" and then it gets stuck on the Input part.

```
typedef struct{
    char disp;
    int cod;
    float costH;
    float costS;
    char nom_emp[50];
    int cod_emp;
    float precio;
}REG;
int main(){
    int end=1;
    int cont, selector;
    REG *registro[28];
    for (int i = 0; i <= cont; i++){
         IngresoRep(&registro[i], i);
         }
}

void IngresoRep(REG * data, int i1){
    //Input and control of device
    scanf("%c", &data->disp); getchar();
    while (data->disp != 'E' && data->disp != 'N' && data->disp != 'T'){
        printf("\nTry again ");
        scanf("%c", &data->disp); getchar();
    }
```

I suspect it may have something to do with the -> use but I'm not too knowledgeable in those departments. Also I don't want to use any "fancier" functions.

Comment: The `"%c"` format with `scanf` will not work as you expect. It will read the newline left over from previous input. Try `" %c"` instead, and note the leading space.

Comment: There is no struct array, there is an array of pointers to struct. Your function expects a pointer to struct, but gets a pointer to pointer to struct. And I think there is a worrying lack of `malloc()`.

Comment: There is also the matter of `cont` which doesn't get initialized before you use it in the `for` loop in `main`.

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple problems, all related to the `registro` array and how you use it:

```
REG *registro[28];
```

Here you have defined an array of `28` pointers to `REG` structures. ***But*** you leave all the pointers uninitialized (which means they will have *indeterminate* (read: garbage) values and are invalid to dereference).

Fortunately, you don'y actually dereference the pointers, instead you use the pointer-to operator on the pointers to get pointers to them:

```
IngresoRep(&registro[i], i);
```

The type of `registro[i]` is `REG *`. The type of `&registro[i]` is `REG **`. That's not what the `IngresoRep` function expects. Since you pass the wrong pointer, you will have *undefined behavior*.

To solve both problems, define `registro` as an array of `REG` *structures*, not pointers:

```
REG registro[28];  // 28 REG structure objects
```

Now using `&registro[i]` in the call to `IngresoRep` will be correct and match what the function expects.

---

Also, you should *really* make a forward declaration of the `IngresoRep` function before the `main` function:

```
// Forward declaration of the function
void IngresoRep(REG * data, int i1);

int main(){
    // ...
}

void IngresoRep(REG * data, int i1){
    // ...
}
```

With this forward declaration the compiler will be able to detect if you pass the wrong arguments to the function, and will warn you about it.

Answer (score 0):

`REG registro[28]; // I removed *`

`registro` is attempting to be an array of data type struct REF, so `*` symbol is not necessary:

- Without `*` what you have is 28 elements of data type struct REG
- With `*` what you have is 28 pointers to data type struct REG

Later the right way to address `registro` elements doesn't include the & operation, the name `registro` is a pointer to the first element, so `registro + i` is a pointer to the `i` element

`IngresoRep(registro+i, i); // IngresoRep(&registro[i], i);`

Answer (score -1):

I'm not too keen on C. But you don't have any data in your REG struct when you initiate your array (REG *registro[28]) therefore your data is probably is going to be set to default 0 for int, and null for character.